# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters doesn't recognize my JsonPropertyNames

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swashbuckle

I am developing a web API in .net-core 3.1

I am currently using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters to show a specific example of the JSON date format. However, when I use this library, it does not take the values ​​of [JsonPropertyName].
My example JSON currently looks like this:

```
{
  "contractCode": 0,
  "registers": 0,
  "totalDue1": 0,
  "totalDue2": 0,
  "buildingExpenses": [
    {
      "ownersAssociationCode": 0,
      "functionalUnitCode": 0,
      "period": "string",
      "ownerName": "string",
      "location": "string",
      "ownerEmail": "string",
      "dueDate1": "21/12/2021",
      "amount1": 0,
      "dueDate2": "21/12/2021",
      "amount2": 0,
      "electronicPaymentCode": "string",
      "barcode": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

And before applying Swashbuckle, it looked like this:

```
{
  "Cliente": 0,
  "CantidadRegistros": 0,
  "TotalesPrimerVencimiento": 0,
  "TotalesSegundoVencimiento": 0,
  "Detalle": [
    {
      "Consorcio": 0,
      "UnidadFuncional": 0,
      "Periodo": "string",
      "Propietario": "string",
      "Ubicacion": "string",
      "Email": "string",
      "FechaPrimerVencimiento": "2022-12-10",
      "ImportePrimerVencimiento": 0,
      "FechaSegundoVencimiento": "2021-12-20",
      "ImporteSegundoVencimiento": 0,
      "CodigoDePagoElectronico": "string",
      "CodigoDeBarras": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want it to now also like this, keeping the example date format that is currently applied (dd/MM/yyyy).

From what I was reading I had to install the Swashbuckle.AspNetcore.Newtonsoft package and add it to my statups, but this did not work for me.

```
services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();
```

This is my Dto that I use and where I apply the JsonPropertyName:

```
public class BuildingExpenseResumeInputDto
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("Cliente")]
        public int ContractCode { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("CantidadRegistros")]
        public int Registers { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("TotalesPrimerVencimiento")]
        public decimal TotalDue1 { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("TotalesSegundoVencimiento")]
        public decimal TotalDue2 { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("Detalle")]
        public List<BuildingExpenseDetailInputDto> BuildingExpenses { get; set; }

        public BuildingExpenseResumeInputDto()
        {
            BuildingExpenses = new List<BuildingExpenseDetailInputDto>();
        }
    }
```

I hope you can help me solve it!

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by updating my Swashbuckle version from 5.0 to 6.2.3 and applying this property to my Dto without the need to use Swashbuckle.Filters:

```
[DefaultValue("31/05/2022")]
```